# character "@" in regex azure search lucene

Tags: azure, lucene.net, azure-cognitive-search

when implementing a search in Azure Search with a text containing the @ character does not return information.

[image]

Comment: should return :"value": [
        {
            "@search.score": 0.57735026,
            "RowKey": "7da261ba-8d90-4c24-bfcf-0ec3b99b5d0b",
            "PartitionKey": "Aplicacion 2",
            "Ip": "10.10.10.10",
            "CodigoHash": "44A41D49B5B5F97CFBCE5C6F3F6AC93C1B23ECAE",
            "TipoEvento": "SISTEMA",
            "TipoMensaje": "EXCEPCION",
            "EntidadOrigen": null,
            "ContenidoMensaje": "{ \"mensaje\": \"prueba@dnp.gov.co\" }",
            "Usuario": "EMANTILLAS",
            "FechaCreacion": "2016-08-09T11:02:15.702Z"
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which analyzer are you using for the search field? If you did not specify an analyzer, it defaults to the lucene standard analyzer which discards punctuations and symbols and the email address abc@bcd.gov.co is tokenized into , , , and . As documented, regex search query only applies to single tokenized terms. The regex /.*bcd.gov.co.*/ doesn't find the email address as it does not match any of the tokenized terms. You can either use whitespace analyzer or a build a [custom one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt605304.aspx) that doesn't discard punctuations or symbols to apply regex matching on the entire address.

Hope this helps. Thanks.

Nate

Comment: Hi Nate, I do not specify an analyzer, if I need a custom analyzer to allow special characters (,; -. _ @) as it should be? you can help me with an example please. thanks in advance.

Comment: This works for me for email:

"analyzers":[
    {
      "name":"analizadorEmail",
      "@odata.type":"#Microsoft.Azure.Search.CustomAnalyzer",
      "tokenizer":"uax_url_email"
    }
  ]
But not for (,; -. _)

Comment: Apparently it works by creating PatternTokenizer including special characters, I'm not sure if it's a good practic but working

Answer (score 0):

### here is sample code

{
                    "name": "Username",
                    "type": "Edm.String",
                    "searchable": true,
                    "filterable": false,
                    "sortable": false,
                    "facetable": false,
                    "analyzer": "email_analyzer"

### },

"analyzers": [
                {
                    "name": "email_analyzer",
                    "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.CustomAnalyzer",
                    "tokenizer": "uax_url_email"
                }

### ]

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others. Thanks for improving the answer's reference value and making it more understandable!